# Spring MVC Java WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.addResourceHandlers

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-java-config

I'm looking at a project with the following Java Configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("spittr.web")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Bean
  public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
  }

  @Override
  public void   configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
  }

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
  }

}
```

The project has some static resources in the webapps/resources directory that are being served up. My question is I'm not sure why. It seems for this to work, the above call to addResourceHandlers(...) should be

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
  registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources");
}
```

I tried to look for something in the Spring documentation possibly indicating default values but could not, so I'm not sure why the project works.

Comment: Can you clarify the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why the configuration file works without the call to registry.addResourceHandler(...).addResourceLocations(...) inside the call to addResourceHandlers(...). Why does it work with just super.addResourceHandlers(registry) ?

Comment: While this may not be an answer but what I have determined is that it defaults to your resource folder under WEB-INF directory by default. I haven't found out anything in documentation but logic dictates that anything exposed to client or needs to be exposed to client (e.g. js, css...) would be stored in a WEB-INF directory, particullary one called resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project can serve static resources thanks to [`DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.html):

> Configures a request handler for serving static resources by forwarding the request to the Servlet container's "default" Servlet.

I use Jetty in the following example, but other servlet containers (e.g. Tomcat) should behave similarly. Download the [Jetty 9](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/) distribution, then inside `webapps`, create these files:

```
example/
    hello.txt
```

Start the Jetty server. We have [deployed the simplest application](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.0.v20150612/quickstart-deploying-webapps.html) imaginable. You should be able to access the file at:

```
http://localhost:8080/example/hello.txt
```

The servlet container can serve static resources without any extra configurations. This behavior is suppressed as soon as Spring MVC comes into play. Spring MVC will create a [front controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern), [`DispatcherServlet`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html), and park it at "/". Every incoming request will go through this single servlet, and the servlet will find the appropriate component in the app to actually process the request (e.g. a [`@RequestMapping`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) method in a [`@Controller`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/Controller.html) class). If no handlers for the request can be found, we have 404s.

The handler `DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer` has the lowest precedence. If enabled, it allows the front controller to handle the request first. When that fails, it forwards the request to the servlet container, where the request is treated as a static resource read.

This is a quick and dirty way of serving static files. In practice, you don't want anything off the beaten path to be available via a GET. You want to allow only specific files and folders, and you would use [`WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.addResourceHandlers()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html#addResourceHandlers-org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry-).

Comment: `addResourceHandlers()` does nothing in this case and should be removed.

Comment: Good point. This example is from chaper 6 of Spring In Action Vol. 4. In chapter 7, the author builds on this project and adds some image files in src/main/webapp/resources/images. There is also a src/main/resources/style.css file. In the WebConfig.java class chp. 7 he has removed the call to addResourceHandlers( ).

Comment: @user88072 I tried your example with Tomcat and it works as you say. I created the hello.txt file and accessed it at localhost:8080/example/hello.txt. So I would use the addResourceHandlers() if I wanted to serve up some static resources in a directory other than under webapps?

Comment: @MikeHT As long as it's on the classpath somehow, yeah.